Problem to insert features into PostGis table with FME
I would like to populate with FME the "public.pdl_steg" table in PostgreSQL/PostGis with features from a "pdls" shapefile layer. public.pdl_steg includes triggers in some fields.


The id_pdls field is of the serial type.
The code_pdls field is unique.
Shapefile “pdls” table:




The triggers work well in PostGis et QGIS.
However, after several attempts, I was unable to add the features from the "pdls" layer to "public.pdl_steg". The execution in FME does not emit any errors and nothing happens.
Any help is welcome.

use fme_db_operation and use your id_pdsl as the unique id https://community.safe.com/data-7/how-do-i-perform-fme-db-operation-on-geopackage-using-an-uuid-no-integer-25079
